# Optional Parameters in methods of Microsoft.VisualBasic Collection

Tags: c#, collections

Me and my co-worker both running the same code ( a C# winforms app)  and both using VS 2010 and set to compile for .NET 3.5 but when we wants to make a call to Microsoft.VisualBasicCollection.Add() method he has to pass all four parameters although the last three of them are optional. Otherwise he will get a compile error.
But on my machine I can just call it without any optional parameters and it compiles fine.
The only difference is that I have also installed ReSharper but I don't think it has to do anything with compiling like that?
Do you have any idea why it is happening?

Thanks

Comment: ...why are you using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection in a C# app

Comment: it is because of its consumer method that we are passing this to it, this C# code has been uplifted from an older VB 6.0 code..

Comment: Computers are stupid. If the setups are same, they'll behave same. Check once more if you are not targeting different versions of C#.

Comment: @SWeko: it is my co-worker's fault! We all had upgraded to 2010 but he was still using VS 2008, so that was the issue.

Comment: How does one even miss that. The UIs look totally different!

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: he is lazy! barely even cleans his monitor! and looks like he had not upgraded to 2010 yet!

Comment: @Matti: Try spending 20 minutes on a conference call with "developers" figuring out what version of Windows they are working with. "Click Start, right-click on My Computer..."  "I don't see 'Start', click where?" -- triple head-desk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is my co-worker's fault! We all had upgraded to 2010 but he was still using VS 2008, so that was the issue

Comment: LOL! I owe him five dollars! will not pay him back now!

Comment: Just say "how about you don't tell anyone I owe you five bucks, and I won't tell anyone you cannot tell the difference between VS 2008 and VS 2010".

Comment: I do have to say, I have serious BOFH twitches every time I hear stories like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use Collection.
2. You are targeting .NET 4.0, where optional parameters are allowed in C#.

Comment: I know. it is because of its consumer method that we are passing this to it, this C# code has been uplifted from an older VB 6.0 code.

Comment: Actually optional parameters are a C# 4.0 language feature, not .NET 4.0. This means you can create a project in Visual Studio 2010, target .NET 2.0 and STILL use optional parameters in C#.

Comment: @RoyGoode: thanks..I hadn't noticed the difference between these two..interesting

Comment: @Roy Goode: of course. I stand corrected. I will be over there in the corner wearing the pointy cap.